# ASM & Transform change classfile: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:

Tags: java, android, java-bytecode-asm

I change the class file in my Gradle Plugin :buildsrc
the class I want to change in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        long var1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        long var2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - var1;
        StringBuilder var3 = new StringBuilder();
        var3.append("org/aigeek/asmapplication/MainActivity.onCreate time:");
        var3.append(var2);
        Log.d("Ken",var3.toString());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mButton = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                //add code here
//                PluginAgent.onClick(view);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and I add the code in MethodVisitor:

```
public class MethodFilterClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
    String superName;
    String[] interfaces;


    public MethodFilterClassVisitor(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM6, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        Log.logEach("*start visit*", Log.accCode2String(access), name, signature, superName, interfaces);
        this.superName = superName;
        this.interfaces = interfaces;
        super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
    }


    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MyMethodVisitor mv = null;
        if (interfaces != null && interfaces.length > 0) {

            if ('onClick(Landroid/view/View;)V' == (name + desc)
                    && interfaces.contains('android/view/View$OnClickListener')) {
                try {
                    MethodVisitor methodVisitor = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
                    mv = new MyMethodVisitor(methodVisitor) {
                        @Override
                        void visitCode() {
                            super.visitCode()
                            methodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/tcl/tracker/PluginAgent", "onClick", "(Landroid/view/View;)V", false);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    mv = null
                }
            }
//            }
            if (mv != null) {
                return mv
            } else {
                return super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use Transform.transform api to change the .class file.
If I do not change the class file, building is ok,
but when I build the project after I changed the class file, I find the error:

```
directory:dest dir /Users/yao/Development/open_android_demo/MyDemos/ASMAndroidDemo/app/build/intermediates/transforms/inject transform for asm/debug/33
====start modify ====org.aigeek.asmapplication.MainActivity=========
*start visit*       ACC_PUBLIC      ACC_SUPER       org/aigeek/asmapplication/MainActivity  null    android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity    []  
====start visit method ====org.aigeek.asmapplication.MainActivity=========
*start visit*       ACC_PUBLIC      ACC_SUPER       org/aigeek/asmapplication/MainActivity  null    android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity    []  
====finish modify ====org.aigeek.asmapplication.MainActivity=========
====start modify ====org.aigeek.asmapplication.MyApplication=========
*start visit*       ACC_PUBLIC      ACC_SUPER       org/aigeek/asmapplication/MyApplication null    android/app/Application []  
====start visit method ====org.aigeek.asmapplication.MyApplication=========
*start visit*       ACC_PUBLIC      ACC_SUPER       org/aigeek/asmapplication/MyApplication null    android/app/Application []  
====finish modify ====org.aigeek.asmapplication.MyApplication=========
====start modify ====org.aigeek.asmapplication.MainActivity$1=========
*start visit*       ACC_SUPER       org/aigeek/asmapplication/MainActivity$1    null    java/lang/Object    [android/view/View$OnClickListener  ]   
====start visit method ====org.aigeek.asmapplication.MainActivity$1=========
*start visit*       ACC_SUPER       org/aigeek/asmapplication/MainActivity$1    null    java/lang/Object    [android/view/View$OnClickListener  ]   
====finish modify ====org.aigeek.asmapplication.MainActivity$1=========
file absolutePath:/Users/yao/Development/open_android_demo/MyDemos/ASMAndroidDemo/app/build/intermediates/transforms/inject transform for asm/debug/33/org/aigeek/asmapplication/MainActivity.class
file absolutePath:/Users/yao/Development/open_android_demo/MyDemos/ASMAndroidDemo/app/build/intermediates/transforms/inject transform for asm/debug/33/org/aigeek/asmapplication/MainActivity$1.class
file absolutePath:/Users/yao/Development/open_android_demo/MyDemos/ASMAndroidDemo/app/build/intermediates/transforms/inject transform for asm/debug/33/org/aigeek/asmapplication/MyApplication.class

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/yao/Development/open_android_demo/MyDemos/ASMAndroidDemo/app/build/intermediates/transforms/inject transform for asm/debug/33
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:420)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$4.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:338)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:327)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:312)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$5(CacheStep.java:83)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:88)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/yao/Development/open_android_demo/MyDemos/ASMAndroidDemo/app/build/intermediates/transforms/inject transform for asm/debug/33
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:909)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:834)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:904)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayDeque.removeFirst(ArrayDeque.java:280)
    at java.util.ArrayDeque.pop(ArrayDeque.java:517)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarState.pop(JarState.java:740)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarState.popReverse(JarState.java:756)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.updateStateForInvoke(JarSourceCode.java:1757)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.updateState(JarSourceCode.java:1748)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.updateState(JarSourceCode.java:1205)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.computeBlockEntryJarStates(JarSourceCode.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.buildPrelude(JarSourceCode.java:366)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRBuilder.build(IRBuilder.java:465)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.internalBuild(JarCode.java:176)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.internalBuildWithLocals(JarCode.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.buildIR(JarCode.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexEncodedMethod.buildIR(DexEncodedMethod.java:300)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.rewriteCode(IRConverter.java:723)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertMethodToDex(IRConverter.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.lambda$convertMethodsToDex$3(IRConverter.java:438)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexClass.forEachMethod(DexClass.java:137)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertMethodsToDex(IRConverter.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.lambda$convertClassesToDex$2(IRConverter.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:258)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:56)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:36)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertClassesToDex(IRConverter.java:423)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertToDex(IRConverter.java:334)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.optimize(D8.java:230)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.lambda$run$1(D8.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
    ... 7 more
    Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:531)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:492)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:83)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ThreadUtils.awaitFutures(ThreadUtils.java:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertClassesToDex(IRConverter.java:425)
        ... 15 more
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.util.NoSuchElementException]


> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/yao/Development/open_android_demo/MyDemos/ASMAndroidDemo/app/build/intermediates/transforms/inject transform for asm/debug/33
```

My Android Studio 3.2
Gradle: 5.2.1
Gradle Plugin:3.3.1

Comment: `if ('onClick(Landroid/view/View;)V' == (name + desc) …` if that was valid Java code, it failed every time, as the result of concatenating `name + desc` is never the same object as the one representing the literal string.

Comment: You are missing some instructions in the code you generate. The static method you are calling (`void com.tcl.tracker.PluginAgent.onClick(android.view.View)`) takes one argument, and that needs to be on the stack, so load local 1 first (local 0 will be `this`, as `onClick` is virtual). You also need a return instruction. A void method still need a return. And finally I am not sure about the call `super.visitCode()`, if that will emit the original code, then you will have a return before the invoke. Find the `.class`file generated and dump it using `javap`, to see the output of you rewrite.

Comment: I find the reason: miss code: mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 1);